# Php Multidimensional array object to Javascript Json

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I've got a multidemnsional array as an object in PHP and like to print it in Javascript. This is as for I've reached.

PHP:

```
$words = $wordlist->getWordlist($var1,$var2);
```

Now i usually printed the array like this in PHP:

```
foreach ($words as $section => $items)
    foreach ($items as $key => $value)
        echo "$key\t = $value";
```

This is what I'm trying to do in Javascript:

```
var coders= <?php print json_encode($words); ?>;

for(var i = 0, l =coders.length; i < l; i++) {
    for(var j = 0, l2 = coders[i].length; j < l2; j++) {
        var value = coders[i][j];
        document.write(value);
    }
}
```

This is my result when i print:

```
document.write(coders);
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

Thanks!

Comment: why not just handle this data with standard object syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't mind using jquery, you can use this:

```
var json_obj = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(json_obj , function(k, v) {  
    $.each(v, function(k2, v2) {
        alert("key is " +k2);
        alert("value is " +v2);         
    });
});
```

where `data` is your json string, like you would receive back from a PHP script `echo json_encode($nested_array)` ajax call

Comment: Solved it by changing to var json_obj= <?php print json_encode($words); ?>; Would work else.

Comment: generally you should avoid putting php directly into your javascript if you can help it. Sure it's quick and easy for simple things, but trust me simple things usually always end up getting more and more added, and before long you have complex bloated spaghetti codebase that's a pain to add onto or fix. Better to make a habit of keeping your html, css js and php separate up front than to have to rewrite everything later...

Comment: My $.02: I'd much rather print a json string via php like this than do an extra ajax call on page load.

Comment: @Bosworth99, most PHP data passed to a webpage is not so static that you'd want to embed it in js like that... if it where, why even use JS? - just have php render the html itself. If you embed dynamic php data in js, than any change requires an entire page load, where as an ajax call would just fetch the new data. I realize that a pageload call seems like overkill for a simple example like this, but its more about thinking ahead and not learning bad habits.... I'm currently untangling 3 years worth of spaghetti PHP/js and I'm constantly kicking myself for not having learned better earlier on

Comment: @WebChemist - of course, you're absolutely right, but its all about circumstance. I'm currently working on a ajax-heavy admin that initiates the process with a big data object holding all manner of user and system variables, which are then used in ajax interactions as the user makes edits / updates etc. It'd certainly be possible to run an initial ajax grab for that stuff, but its pretty convenient to just have it ready to go as the page loads.